# google api images search doesn't work

Tags: image, api, search

I'm trying that https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list
tool to create images search query.
Params
cx: 017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve
searchType: image
num: 1
q: simon cat

And when I submit form I can see only empty response.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing same problem. I solved it by creating CSE.

1- You should visit http://www.google.com/cse and create custom search engine. 
2- After step 1 you shoud enable image search in configuration of CSE
[image: enable image search]

3- you should use your own cx: you can also find it in CSE basic information tab.

Goodluck !

Comment: Also worth to note that you should "search the entire web but emphasize included sites" to get more results

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem today and by reading the CSE configuration, there is an **Advanced Option** where you tell the engine from which sites it should look for.

Set that option to "Search the entire web but emphasize included sites" and you can leave empty the list of included sites. Hope this helps.

[image: Sites to seach option]